# Counting occurrences of an item not giving exactly in android

Tags: java, android, count

I am trying to count the occurrence of the each string. If the month matches with current, then I'm displaying count of the that string.

Suppose this month is `07` and `modifiedtime` months are like `07, 06, 09, 06, 07` in that what are the month `07` are there for that month what is count of the each item

Example: Month = `07` , count of opportunity should be `1`,

output:

What I'm getting :

```
Count_opportunity:02
Count_proposal:02
Count_negotiation:01
Count_won:32
Count_lost:17
```

Desired output:

```
Count_opportunity:01
Count_proposal:0
Count_negotiation:0
Count_won:0
Count_lost:0
```

The following code gives me a wrong count. Can some-one detect the error?

```
    private void workingOnResponseMonthwiseOpportunity(SyncModule syncModule){
    
        String success = syncModule.getSuccess();

        if (success.equals("true")) {
            SyncResults results = syncModule.getResult();
            Sync sync = results.getSync();
            ArrayList<SyncUpdated> syncUpdateds = sync.getUpdated();

            for (SyncUpdated syncUpdated : syncUpdateds) {

                ArrayList<SyncBlocks> syncBlocks = syncUpdated.getBlocks();

                String scheduleDates = "";
                String scheduleDate = "";
                String supportrequired="";
                String winprob="";
                String salesstage="";
                String modality="";
                String modifydatetime="";
                String modifiedtime="";
                String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

                for (SyncBlocks syncBlocks1 : syncBlocks) {

                    String label = syncBlocks1.getLabel();
                    if (label.equals("Basic Information")) {
                        ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {
                            name = synFields1.getName();
                            values = synFields1.getValue();


                            //sales stage
                            if (name.equals("sales_stage")) {
                                salesstage = String.valueOf(values);
                                salesstage_list.add(salesstage);
                                //support required
                            }
                           
                        }
                    }
                    else if (label.equals("Opportunity Details")) {

                        ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {

                            String name = synFields1.getName();
                            values = synFields1.getValue();

                            if (("modifiedtime".equals(name))) {
                                modifydatetime = String.valueOf(values);
                                Log.d("modifydatetime",modifydatetime);

                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    modifiedmonth= LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.parse(modifydatetime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
                                    Log.d("modifiedmonth", String.valueOf(modifiedmonth));
                                    break;                                   
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    PreferenceManagerMyOpportunity.getInstance(requireContext()).setMultipleDataOpportunity(scheduleDate, salesstage, supportrequired, winprob, modality,modifiedtime);

                    }

                    MyOpportunityModel opportunityModel = new MyOpportunityModel(scheduleDate, salesstage, supportrequired, winprob, modality, modifydatetime);
        
                    java.time.LocalDate today = java.time.LocalDate.now();
                    int month=today.getMonthValue();
                    Log.d("month",String.valueOf(month));
                    boolean isModifiedThisMonth =modifiedmonth==month;
                    Log.d("isModifiedThisMonth",String.valueOf(isModifiedThisMonth));

                    if (isModifiedThisMonth) {
                            //Sales stage starts
                            Count_opportunity = Collections.frequency(salesstage_list, "Opportunity");
                             System.out.println("Count_opportunity:  "+ Count_opportunity);
                                Count_proposal = Collections.frequency(salesstage_list, "Proposal or Price Quote");
                                //System.out.println("Count of In Complete is:  "+ Count_Incomplete);

                                Count_negotiation = Collections.frequency(salesstage_list, "Negotiation or Review");
                                Count_won = Collections.frequency(salesstage_list, "Closed Won");
                                Count_lost = Collections.frequency(salesstage_list, "Closed Lost");
                                // System.out.println("Count of Completed is:  "+ Complted_Count);
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, where is this `salesstage_list` coming from, and how is it created/populated?

Comment: Pls have a look once